# htaccess rewrite to remove query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite the following:

```
 http://www.mystuff.com/drinks/category/beer?page=1
```

to

```
 https://www.mystuff.com/food-drink/beer/ale
```

No matter what I try the URI rewrite to the new address but it keeps the query string attached.  I need to lose this.  I've tried so many options and none seem to work, can anybody ofgfer some advice. 
I thought this would do it, but no:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  (.*)(?:^|&)page=(?:[^&]*)((?:&|$).*)
RewriteCond %1%2 (^|&)([^&].*|$)
RewriteRule ^(/drinks/category/beer)$ https://www.mystuff.com/food-drink/beer/ale  [R=301, L]
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an empty query string to truncate it on the rewrite. Add a single `?` to the end of the rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  (.*)(?:^|&)page=(?:[^&]*)((?:&|$).*)
RewriteCond %1%2 (^|&)([^&].*|$)
RewriteRule ^(/drinks/category/beer)$ https://www.mystuff.com/food-drink/beer/ale?  [R=301, L]
```