# .htaccess dynamic URL redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect, dynamic

Unable to redirect dynamic URL after rewriting it.

Dynamic URL: http://localhost/amploutargetsharing/campaigninfo.php?unique_hash=f5f386e

after Redirection I want the URL to look like below.

Desired URL: http://localhost/amploutargetsharing/f5f386e

As I google this and write below code.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/amploutargetsharing/campaigninfo\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^unique_hash=([a-z0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/amploutargetsharing/%1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ campaigninfo.php?unique_hash=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And above code is giving me the below result.

http//localhost/amploutargetsharing/f5f386e?unique_hash=f5f386e

But I want the URL to look like the above desired URL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [htaccess rewrite to remove query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30591437/htaccess-rewrite-to-remove-query-string)

Comment: yes it is a real directory Anubhava Sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these rules in `/amploutargetsharing/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /amploutargetsharing/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /campaigninfo.php\?unique_hash=([^&\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %1? [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ campaigninfo.php?unique_hash=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: sir, Thank you so much for your kind help your code really working fine. :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /amploutargetsharing/campaigninfo.php\?unique_hash=([^&\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ amploutargetsharing/%1? [NC,R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ amploutargetsharing/campaigninfo.php?unique_hash=$2  [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: @Starkeen Sir, with your above code I am getting an error of 
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
Tue Jul 14 08:43:26 2015
Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1

and New URL become like this.

http://localhost/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/amploutargetsharing/amploutargetsharing/f5f386e

Comment: @anubhava Sir, I am getting the above error in comment.

Comment: @AsifAnsari: Add `RewriteBase /` line just below `RewriteEngine On` and retest.

Comment: @anubhava sir, thank you for your kind reply ,  i add the line you guided, 
now the URL become my desired URL (http://localhost/amploutargetsharing/f5f386e) 
but I am still getting the same error. 


Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost
Tue Jul 14 12:32:52 2015
Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1

Comment: Probably you have this htaccess in `amploutargetsharing`. Move it a level above.

Comment: @anubhava sir, yes i have this htaccess in amploutargetsharing folder itself and that is my root folder. i do not understand by Move it a level above means.. because amploutargetsharing is my root dir. :(